# Wordpress subpages not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have this wordpress site and all of a sudden subpages stopped working, This has happened before and I fixed it now its back, whats wrong with my rewrite rules? I get a 404 error, this is a wordpress page a made called /about-us

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

~

Comment: Everything between `# BEGIN` and `# END` is automatically put there by WordPress whenever you change certain settings from the ACP.  Why would you be editing `htaccess` directly?

Comment: Please create a verifiable example of your problem. Give us steps on how to reproduce the problem you have.

Comment: The steps to reproduce the issue are the following. I goto http://www.example.com and it works, if I goto http://www.example.com/about-us it does not work. The wordpress site was originally on another server and is now on a new one.

Comment: When I change my Permalinks to Post Name, a message appears, You should update your web.config now. I dont know where my web.config is or what I should put.

Comment: How did you find that it's caused by .htaccess rules?

Comment: I am not sure. It could be anything at this point as my .htaccess sounds good,.

Comment: `web.config` is usually used in IIS. Is your site hosted on a Windows server? If that is the case, the contents of your `.htaccess` file won't matter.

Comment: Yes that is the case, my site is hosted on a Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your WordPress site isn't working is that you've migrated from Apache to IIS without migrating your rewrite rules from your `.htaccess` to `Web.config` file. Hence, all the WordPress pretty links are failing because IIS isn't rewriting them as it never reads an `.htaccess` file.

You need to find the `Web.config` file located in the same directory as your WordPress. If you do not have a `Web.config` file there, create it as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now just add the following rewrite rule inside the `<system.webServer>` element of your existing or newly created `Web.config` file.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="WordPress" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rule above works the same way as in your `.htaccess` file. It matches any requested URL that does not correspond to any existing file or directory and forwards the request to `index.php` which figures out which article to serve from the requested pretty link still available through the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.